# Conditional expectation for non-gaussian variables

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $A$, $B$ be two zero-mean random variables. Let the variance be $\sigma^2_A$, $\sigma^2_B$ and let the correlation be $\sigma_{AB}$. Consider the following expression :-

$$
\mathbb{E}\big[A|B=b\big]
$$
When $A,B$ are jointly gaussians the above expression is equal to $$\frac{b\sigma_{AB}}{\sigma^2_B}$$

1. Can we upper bound the above expression for a larger class of distributions?
2. Can we say **anything** about the expression?

Answer (score 4):

**Without making additional assumptions, there is little one can say.**

The idea behind the examples given here is that in the regression of $A$ against $B$, we may take a tiny bit of the range of $B$ (for which there is low probability $q$) and drastically alter the conditional distribution of $A$ in that range without changing any of the lower bivariate moments very much.

[image: Figure]

*The bivariate Normal distribution, whose density is shown as a contour plot at the left, has been altered within a narrow strip of horizontal ($B$) values by shifting all vertical ($A$) densities upwards.  To compensate, (1) the remaining density was shifted slightly downward (thus rebalancing the expectation of $A$) and (2) the remaining density was contracted in the vertical direction (thus reducing the overall variance of $A$ to compensate for the slight increase caused by the initial shift within the strip).*

**By making the strip sufficiently narrow, we can shift as much probability of $A$ as we want arbitrarily much (up or down) while keeping the compensating effects on the remainder of the distribution arbitrarily small.**  (Furthermore, by situating the strip near the middle (horizontally), we can also arrange not to disturb the correlation coefficient if we wish.)

---

The following explicit example takes this idea to an extreme by supposing both $A$ and $B$ have only two possible values each, but there's nothing special about this extreme case.

Assume $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ are both nonzero. Given any nonzero numbers $x\gt 0$ and $y$ and $0\lt q \lt 1$, define a bivariate distribution for $(A,B)$ as follows:

$$\eqalign{
\Pr((A,B)=(0,0)) &= q/2 \\
\Pr((A,B)=(x,0)) &= q/2 \\
\Pr((A,B)=(0,y)) &= 1-q.
}$$

This makes $A$ a multiple $x$ of a Bernoulli$(q/2)$ variable and $B$ is a multiple $y$ of a Bernoulli$(1-q)$ variable.  Therefore

$$\sigma^2_A = x^2\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{q}{2}\right);\quad
\sigma^2_B = y^2 q(1-q).$$

These determine $x^2$ and $y^2$ in terms of $q$ and the given variances:

$$x^2 = \frac{4\sigma^2_A}{q(2-q)};\quad y^2 = \frac{\sigma^2_B}{q(1-q)}.$$

From the definition of conditional expectation

$$\mathbb{E}(A|B=0) = \frac{0(q/2) + x(q/2)}{q/2 + q/2} = \frac{x}{2} =  \frac{\sigma_A}{\sqrt{q(2-q)}}.\tag{1}$$

Obviously we can make the right hand side as large as we wish by making $q$ sufficiently small.  Rigorously, if $N \gt 0$, pick $q \gt 0$ such that $q \lt \sigma^2_A/(2N^2)$, so that

$$q(2-q) = 1-(1-q)^2 \lt 1-(1-\sigma^2_A/(2N^2))^2 = \frac{\sigma^2_A}{N^2} - \left(\frac{\sigma_A^2}{2N^2}\right)^2 \lt \frac{\sigma^2_A}{N^2},$$

implying (from expression $(1)$) that

$$\mathbb{E}(A|B=0) =  \frac{\sigma_A}{\sqrt{q(2-q)}} \gt  \frac{\sigma_A}{\sigma_A/N} = N.$$

**Thus we may select $q$ to match the intended variances of the distribution of $(A,B)$ while making $\mathbb{E}(A|B=0)$ arbitrarily large.**

Comment: Looks like we might need some smoothness guarantees. Opinion?

Comment: @Vivek they won't help. There are smooth examples arbitrarily close to the examples given here.